# Get FB likers details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

How to get fb likers details from [here](https://www.facebook.com/about/graphsearch). For eg: The query "People who like Saavn(Music page) from India" returns users. Is there a way to get the results programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Graph Search is only available on facebook.com, you can´t access it with the Graph API. You can only search for Users with their name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search